# Parse Date in Bash

Tags: bash, date, parsing

How would you parse a date in bash, with separate fields (years, months, days, hours, minutes, seconds) into different variables?

The date format is: `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss`

Answer (score 99):

Does it have to be bash?  You can use the GNU coreutils `/bin/date` binary for many transformations:

```
 $ date --date="2009-01-02 03:04:05" "+%d %B of %Y at %H:%M and %S seconds"
 02 January of 2009 at 03:04 and 05 seconds
```

This parses the given date and displays it in the chosen format.  You can adapt that at will to your needs.

Comment: Is this a Linux extension?  Neither FreeBSD or Mac OSX seem to support it.

Comment: It's plain old GNU date:

$ date --version
date (GNU coreutils) 7.4
Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by David MacKenzie.

Comment: `date --date="\`date\`"` works for me and produces same output as date. Version is `date (GNU coreutils) 8.20`. Which `date` do you use ?

Comment: `--date` / `-d` is a GNU extension. POSIX only specifies one option (`-u`) for `date`. You can use `date -jf '%F %T' '2009-01-02 03:04:05' '+%d %B of %Y at %H:%M and %S seconds'` with BSD / OS X date.

Comment: @user495470 What would the format be if the time was 12 hour format?

Answer (score 52):

I had a different input time format, so here is a more flexible solution.

## Convert dates in BSD/macOS

```
date -jf in_format [+out_format] in_date
```

where the formats use strftime (see [`man strftime`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=strftime&sektion=3)).

For the given input format `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss`:

```
$ date -jf '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' '2017-05-10 13:40:01'
Wed May 10 13:40:01 PDT 2017
```

To read them into separate variables, I'm taking NVRAM's idea, but allowing you to use any strftime format:

```
$ date_in='2017-05-10 13:40:01'

$ format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'

$ read -r y m d H M S <<< "$(date -jf "$format" '+%Y %m %d %H %M %S' "$date_in")"

$ for var in y m d H M S; do echo "$var=${!var}"; done
y=2017
m=05
d=10
H=13
M=40
S=01
```

> In scripts, [always](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2162) use [`read -r`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/192790/92723).

In my case, I wanted to convert between timezones (see your `/usr/share/zoneinfo` directory for zone names):

```
$ format=%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z

$ TZ=UTC date -jf $format +$format 2017-05-10T02:40:01+0200
2017-05-10T00:40:01+0000

$ TZ=America/Los_Angeles date -jf $format +$format 2017-05-10T02:40:01+0200
2017-05-09T17:40:01-0700
```

## Convert dates in GNU/Linux

> On a Mac, you can install the GNU version of `date` as `gdate` with `brew install coreutils`.

```
date [+out_format] -d in_date
```

where the out_format uses strftime (see [`man strftime`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html)).

In GNU coreutils' `date` command, there is no way to explicitly set an input format, since it tries to figure out the input format by itself, and stuff usually just works. (For detail, you can read the manual at [coreutils: Date input formats](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Date-input-formats.html#Date-input-formats).)

For example:

```
$ date '+%Y %m %d %H %M %S' -d '2017-05-10 13:40:01'
2017 05 10 13 40 01
```

To read them into separate variables:

```
$ read -r y m d H M S <<< "$(date '+%Y %m %d %H %M %S' -d "$date_in")"
```

To convert between timezones (see your `/usr/share/zoneinfo` directory for zone names), you can specify `TZ="America/Los_Angeles"` right in your input string. Note the literal `"` chars around the zone name, and the space character before in_date:

```
TZ=out_tz date [+out_format] 'TZ="in_tz" in_date'
```

For example:

```
$ format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z'

$ TZ=America/Los_Angeles date +"$format" -d 'TZ="UTC" 2017-05-10 02:40:01'
2017-05-09 19:40:01-0700

$ TZ=UTC date +"$format" -d 'TZ="America/Los_Angeles" 2017-05-09 19:40:01'
2017-05-10 02:40:01+0000
```

GNU date also understands hour offsets for the time zone:

```
$ TZ=UTC date +"$format" -d '2017-05-09 19:40:01-0700'
2017-05-10 02:40:01+0000
```

Answer (score 38):

This is simple, just convert your dashes and colons to a space (no need to change IFS) and use 'read' all on one line:

```
read Y M D h m s <<< ${date//[-:]/ }
```

For example:

```
$ date=$(date +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
$ read Y M D h m s <<< ${date//[-: ]/ }
$ echo "Y=$Y, m=$m"
Y=2009, m=57
```

Comment: On Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS, this gives me `Syntax error: redirection unexpected`

Comment: Are you sure you're running bash?  If so, what version?  Check $SHELL (or `ps -fp $$`) if interactive or the shebang if it's a script.  It works fine on bash 4.3.48 (Ubu 16.04.5 LTS).

Answer (score 7):

```
$ t='2009-12-03 12:38:15'
$ a=(`echo $t | sed -e 's/[:-]/ /g'`)
$ echo ${a[*]}
2009 12 03 12 38 15
$ echo ${a[3]}
12
```

Answer (score 6):

The array method is perhaps better, but this is what you were specifically asking for:

```
IFS=" :-"
read year month day hour minute second < <(echo "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss")
```

Comment: I like this best.  One shortcut, which also doesn't permanently change IFS: `IFS=" :-" read Y M D h m s <<<"YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss"`

Answer (score 3):

Pure Bash:

```
date="2009-12-03 15:35:11"
saveIFS="$IFS"
IFS="- :"
date=($date)
IFS="$saveIFS"
for field in "${date[@]}"
do
    echo $field
done

2009
12
03
15
35
11
```

Comment: No need to use arrays here. Just `set junk $date; shift` instead of `date=($date)` and `for field` instead of the array loop. That would be a `pure sh` version, which is even better!

Answer (score 2):

instead of using the shell scripting,incorporate in your scripting itself like below wheever you need:

```
a=date +%Y 
b=date +%S
c=date +%H
```

a will be year
b will be seconds
c will be hours. and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution to the OP's problem:

```
IFS=' -:' read y m d h m s<<<'2014-03-26 16:36:41'
```

Converting a date to another format with BSD `date` and GNU `date`:

```
$ LC_ALL=C date -jf '%a %b %e %H:%M:%S %Z %Y' 'Wed Mar 26 16:36:41 EET 2014' +%F\ %T
2014-03-26 16:36:41
$ gdate -d 'Wed Mar 26 16:36:41 EET 2014' +%F\ %T
2014-03-26 16:36:41
```

GNU `date` recognizes `Wed` and `Mar` even in non-English locales but BSD `date` doesn't.

Converting seconds since epoch to a date and time with GNU date and BSD date:

```
$ gdate -d @1234567890 '+%F %T'
2009-02-14 01:31:30
$ date -r 1234567890 '+%F %T'
2009-02-14 01:31:30
```

Converting seconds to hours, minutes, and seconds with a POSIX shell, POSIX `awk`, GNU `date`, and BSD `date`:

```
$ s=12345;printf '%02d:%02d:%02d\n' $((s/3600)) $((s%3600/60)) $((s%60))
05:25:45
$ echo 12345|awk '{printf "%02d:%02d:%02d\n",$0/3600,$0%3600/60,$0%60}'
05:25:45
$ gdate -d @12345 +%T
05:25:45
$ date -r 12345 +%T
05:25:45
```

Converting seconds to days, hours, minutes, and seconds:

```
$ t=12345678
$ printf '%d:%02d:%02d:%02d\n' $((t/86400)) $((t/3600%24)) $((t/60%60)) $((t%60))
142:21:21:18
```

Answer (score 1):

another pure bash

```
$ d="2009-12-03 15:35:11"
$ d=${d//[- :]/|}
$ IFS="|"
$ set -- $d
$ echo $1
2009
$ echo $2
12
$ echo $@
2009 12 03 15 35 11
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using cut?
something like this:
dayofweek=`date|cut -d" " -f1`

Comment: That only separates the date and the time, not each part individually.