# Convert string to date in bash

Tags: string, bash, shell, unix, date

I have a string in the format "yyyymmdd". It is a string in bash and I want to get it converted into a date so that all other date functions can be used on it.

"20121212" string into "20121212" date with format "%Y%m%d".

Comment: bash doesn't have a date type. What are these "all other date functions" you're talking about?

Comment: Say I want to add 7 days to a date. I think that can be done on bash. It is not simple integer addition at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse Date in Bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1842634/parse-date-in-bash)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

This worked for me :

```
date -d '20121212 7 days'
date -d '12-DEC-2012 7 days'
date -d '2012-12-12 7 days'
date -d '2012-12-12 4:10:10PM 7 days'
date -d '2012-12-12 16:10:55 7 days'
```

then you can format output adding parameter '+%Y%m%d'

Comment: Does date support converting from ISO-8601

Comment: @CMCDragonkai `now=$(date -Im)` stores the current time as an ISO-8601 date/time to minute precision, and `date -d = $now` is happy with that format.  I'm not sure though if the same is necessarily true for all of the variants which are ISO-8601 compatible.

Comment: This is certainly useful, and gnu date also does things like converting time zones, but there's a lot of other date manipulation tasks one might want.  E.g. Difference between dates to get an interval; Rounding of both dates and intervals to a given precision (round down, round up and round to nearest), or stretching things further, how would I find the date in 10 business days time from date X (given the holidays of a given country).  Is there a more comprehensive tool suitable for scripting use?

Comment: @mc0e Only ones I know of are language specific libraries, not CLI executables. Perhaps one could wrap them up into a CLI binary. Like Moment in JS and some other ones.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai Yeah, I was thinking wrapping up an existing library with a CLI seemed like a good idea. That said, reading [this](http://www.unix.com/man-page/debian/3pm/date::manip::misc/) is worthwhile before anyone jumps in too quick.  Probably the best solution would be a CLI around a C or C++ library, if there's a good one to hand.

Comment: Why did you put "7 days" in all of your examples? It works without these data. Just `date -d '20121212' +%Y%m%d` will do what author wants

Comment: @VictorPerov It's what the author asked for in the comments of his question.

Answer (score 39):

We can use date -d option

1) Change format to "%Y-%m-%d" format i.e 20121212 to 2012-12-12

```
date -d '20121212' +'%Y-%m-%d'
```

2)Get next or last day from a given date=20121212. Like get a date 7 days in past with specific format

```
date -d '20121212 -7 days' +'%Y-%m-%d'
```

3) If we are getting date in some variable say dat

```
dat2=$(date -d "$dat -1 days" +'%Y%m%d')
```

Comment: i was exactly looking for the number 3 solution, thanks @minhas23

Answer (score 12):

date only work with GNU date (usually comes with Linux)

for OS X, two choices:

1. change command (verified)

   > ```
   > #!/bin/sh
   > #DATE=20090801204150
   > #date -jf "%Y%m%d%H%M%S" $DATE "+date \"%A,%_d %B %Y %H:%M:%S\""
   > date "Saturday, 1 August 2009 20:41:50"
   > ```
   >
   > http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/116310-date-conversion.html
2. Download the GNU Utilities from Coreutils - GNU core utilities (not verified yet)
   http://www.unix.com/emergency-unix-and-linux-support/199565-convert-string-date-add-1-a.html

Answer (score 5):

just use the -d option of the date command, e.g.

```
date -d '20121212' +'%Y %m'
```