# Bash - convert string to date

Tags: bash

I need to convert to date in bash a string which has the hour included, such as: 2012-02-09-18, and store the result inside a variable, so that I can compare such strings as dates. If I use for conversion

```
  date -d "2012-02-09-18"
```

it will crash with "Invalid date error". How can I do this?

Comment: Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11144408/convert-string-to-date-in-bash

Comment: what would be the desired output? because it is not clear if you want to remove the hour or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can tweak input to make it parseable by `date` using `sed`:

```
str='2012-02-09-18'

date -d "$(sed 's/-\([^-]*\)$/ \1/' <<< "$str")"
Thu Feb  9 18:00:00 EST 2012
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this with bash's [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe):

```
a="2012-02-09-18"
date -d "${a%-*} ${a#*-*-*-*}"
```

Output:

```
Thu Feb  9 18:00:00 CET 2012
```