# How to convert string format date yyyymmddThhmmss.sss to date in Bash?

Tags: linux, bash

I have date in string variable in this format: yyyymmddThhmmss.sss. For example: 20171115T102601.259
How can i convert this string to date in Bash?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert string to date in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11144408/convert-string-to-date-in-bash)

Comment: this is not duplicate of what you suggested @abcalphabet

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse Date in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1842634/parse-date-in-bash)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this

```
dt=$(sed -E "s/([0-9]{8})T([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})/\1 \2:\3:\4/" <<< "20171115T102601.259")

date  -d "$dt"
```