# Unix string to date conversion, what is wrong

Tags: date, unix

I know the topic has already emerged and some of the posts give a good summary like the one here: [Convert string to date in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11144408/convert-string-to-date-in-bash) . Nevertheless, I encounter a problem presented below with an example I should solve:

`date +'%d.%m.%y'` works as desired and returns `05.12.20` but the inverse operation I should use to convert strings to date fails:

```
date -d "05.12.20" +'%d.%m.%y'
date: invalid date â€˜05.12.20â€™
```

and this is exactly what I need. The Unix date formatting I have also checked on https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-formatting-dates-for-display/ but it seems to be in line with that. What is the problem? I also tried to supply time zone indicators like CEST but they did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
date -d "05-12-20" +'%d.%m.%y'
```

UNIX `date` expects either `-` or `/` as a date separator.

However, if your input really must be in the format "05.12.20" (i.e. using `.`), then you can convert it to the format expected by UNIX `date`:

```
date -d `echo "05.12.20" | sed 's/\./-/g'` +'%d.%m.%y'
```

Comment: My separator is the dot, so the questions is how to get it working with the dot. Anyway, thanks for the response and for reading the post!

Comment: Ok, sure, thanks for the clarification. I've updated the answer with a possible alternative that could work for you.

Comment: Warning about "UNIX". `date` can decode also spaces and commas (as the examples in man pages) "and other formats to long to describe in a manual page". Note `-d` is also not in POSIX compatible (and mac has `-f` to handle input format, but non on GNU date)