# Convert any Date format in unix

Tags: linux, unix, date

How can I convert any user inputted date into `yyyy/mm/dd`?

For example, the user may input date in one of the following formats:

```
20120121
2012-01-21
01/21/2012
01/21/2012
...
```

But I need to convert any of the date entered by the user into `yyyy/mm/dd (2012/01/2012)`. Any suggestion?

Here's what I've been trying, but it is not working:

```
echo "Please enter the date: " 
read X 
a=$X+"%y/%m/%d"
echo $a
```

Comment: Could this help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/1842754/16959

Comment: Are you sure you want to handle *any* format?  What if the user enters "The third weekend of the fourth decade after the first bicentennial anniversary of my parent's wedding"?

Comment: Agree with that link.  Use the `date` command.  Note that you can't convert "any" date format - Some dates are ambiguous: *eg* 01/02/2012 -- is that the 1st of feb (as I would see it), or the 2nd of january (as americans would see it)

Comment: Maybe it could pass any format that generates an exception to [Chandler](http://chandlerproject.org/) :)  sorry I've been reading Dreaming in Code

Answer (score 0):

You can try this command:

```
#!/bin/bash

date='2013-01-23'
from='%Y-%m-%d'
to='%Y/%m/%d'
python -c 'import sys, datetime; print(datetime.datetime.strptime(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2]).strftime(sys.argv[3]))' $date $from $to
```