# Parsing date and time format - Bash

Tags: bash, parsing, awk, sed

I have date and time format like this(yearmonthday):

```
20141105 11:30:00
```

I need assignment year, month, day, hour and minute values to variable.

I can do it year, day and hour like this:

```
year=$(awk '{print $1}' log.log | sed 's/^\(....\).*/\1/')
day=$(awk '{print $1}' log.log | sed 's/^.*\(..\).*/\1/')  
hour=$(awk '{print $2}' log.log | sed 's/^\(..\).*/\1/')
```

How can I do this for month and minute?

--

And I need that every line of my log file:

```
20141105 11:30:00 /bla/text.1
20141105 11:35:00 /bla/text.2
20141105 11:40:00 /bla/text.3
....
```

I'm trying read line by line this log file and do this:

```
mkdir -p "/bla/backup/$year/$month/$day/$hour/$minute"
mv $file "/bla/backup/$year/$month/$day/$hour/$minute"
```

Here is my not working code:

```
#!/bin/bash
LOG=/var/log/LOG

while read line
do

year=${line:0:4}
month=${line:4:2}
day=${line:6:2}
hour=${line:9:2}
minute=${line:12:2}
file=$(awk '{print $3}')

if [ -f "$file" ]; then

printf -v path "%s/%s/%s/%s/%s" $year $month $day $hour $minute
mkdir -p "/bla/backup/$path"
mv $file "/bla/backup/$path"

fi
done < $LOG
```

Comment: What is your end goal, why are they being put in variables ?

Comment: I need to create path like this -> /bla/2014/11/05/11/30/

Comment: where are you getting the date from ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse Date in Bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1842634/parse-date-in-bash)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to call out to awk to date at all, use bash's substring operations

```
d="20141105 11:30:00"
yr=${d:0:4}
mo=${d:4:2}
dy=${d:6:2}
hr=${d:9:2}
mi=${d:12:2}
printf -v dir "/bla/%s/%s/%s/%s/%s/\n" $yr $mo $dy $hr $mi
echo "$dir"
```

```
/bla/2014/11/05/11/30/
```

Or directly, without all the variables.

```
printf -v dir "/bla/%s/%s/%s/%s/%s/\n" ${d:0:4} ${d:4:2} ${d:6:2} ${d:9:2} ${d:12:2}
```

---

Given your log file:

```
while read -r date time file; do
    d="$date $time"
    printf -v dir "/bla/%s/%s/%s/%s/%s/\n" ${d:0:4} ${d:4:2} ${d:6:2} ${d:9:2} ${d:12:2}
    mkdir -p "$dir"
    mv "$file" "$dir"
done < filename
```

or, making a big assumption that there are no whitespace or globbing characters in your filenames:

```
sed -r 's#(....)(..)(..) (..):(..):.. (.*)#mv \6 /blah/\1/\2/\3/\4/\5#' | sh
```

Comment: How can I do this all line of my log files?

Comment: edit your question to show a sample of your log file.

Answer (score 1):

`date` command also do this work

```
#!/bin/bash
year=$(date  +'%Y' -d'20141105 11:30:00')
day=$(date  +'%d' -d'20141105 11:30:00')
month=$(date  +'%m' -d'20141105 11:30:00')
minutes=$(date  +'%M' -d'20141105 11:30:00')
echo  "$year---$day---$month---$minutes"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use only one `awk`

```
month=$(awk '{print substr($1,5,2)}' log.log)
year=$(awk '{print substr($1,0,4)}' log.log)
minute=$(awk '{print substr($2,4,2)}' log.log)
etc
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are processing the log file, which each line starts with the date string. You may have already written a loop to handle each line, in your loop, you could do:

```
d="$(awk '{print $1,$2}' <<<"$line")"
year=$(date -d"$d" +%Y)
month=$(date -d"$d" +%m)
day=$(date -d"$d" +%d)
min=$(date -d"$d" +%M)
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't repeat yourself.

```
d='20141105 11:30:00'
IFS=' ' read -r year month day min < <(date -d"$d" '+%Y %d %m %M')

echo "year: $year"
echo "month: $month"
echo "day: $day"
echo "min: $min"
```

The trick is to ask `date` to output the fields you want, separated by a character (here a space), to put this character in `IFS` and ask `read` to do the splitting for you. Like so, you're only executing `date` once and only spawn one subshell.

If the date comes from the first line of the file `log.log`, here's how you can assign it to the variable `d`:

```
IFS= read -r d < log.log
```

Answer (score 1):

```
eval "$( 
   echo '20141105 11:30:00' \
    | sed 'G;s/\(....\)\(..\)\(..\) \(..\):\(..\):\(..\) *\(.\)/Year=\1\7Month=\2\7Day=\3\7Hour=\4\7Min=\5\7Sec=\6/'
    )"
```

pass via a assignation string to evaluate. You could easily adapt to also check the content by replacing dot per more specific pattern like `[0-5][0-9]` for min and sec, ...

posix version so `--posix` on GNU sed

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a function that I usually cut and paste into my script files

```
function getdate()
{
  local a
  a=(`date "+%Y %m %d %H %M %S" | sed -e 's/ / /'`)
  year=${a[0]}
  month=${a[1]}
  day=${a[2]}
  hour=${a[3]}
  minute=${a[4]}
  sec=${a[5]}
}
```

in the script file, on a line of it's own

getdate

echo "year=$year,month=$month,day=$day,hour=$hour,minute=$minute,second=$sec"

Of course, you can modify what I provided or use answer [6] above.
The function takes no arguments.