# Shell Scripts Integer Expression Expected

Tags: linux, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to run the following script in bash

```
#greetings
set `date`
if [ "$4" -lt 12 ]
then 
  echo "Good Morning"
elif [ "$4" -lt 18 ]
  echo "Good Afternoon"
else
  echo "Good evening"
fi
exit
```

I keep geeting the error ./greetings: line 3: [: 06:19:20: integer expression expected

What should i do?

Comment: should it be just `$4` instead of "$4"

Comment: I tried that didn't work

Comment: What do you pass as `$4` when you're running the script? Because `-lt` require standard numbers. I.E. 12, 13 or 12.5. If you pass 12:30, bash can't parse `:`. So it throws that error.

Comment: Do you have a fix for that?

Comment: Try converting `$4` to an actual date and it should work.

Comment: How do i do that?

Comment: You're also missing `then` after `elif`.

Comment: this may useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1842634/parse-date-in-bash

Answer (score 1):

If you try to `echo $4` at the very beginning of the script, you'll get a result of the following format:

```
%H:%M:%S
```

For example,

```
$ date
16:41:22
```

This result can't be parsed as integer.

One solution would be setting only the hours instead of the whole date, and use `$1` (instead of `$4`):

```
# greetings
set `date +%H`
if [ "$1" -lt 12 ]
then
  echo "Good Morning"
elif [ "$1" -lt 18 ]
then
  echo "Good Afternoon"
else
  echo "Good evening"
fi
exit
```

Also, please note that you're missing `then` keyword after `elif`.

Comment: The command set `date` sets the fourth parameter to the value of the time

Comment: @YousifShibeika Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
TIME=`date +%H:%M:%S | awk -F: '{ print ($1 * 3600) + ($2 * 60) + $3 }'`

if [ "$TIME" -lt 43200 ]; then 
  echo "Good Morning"
elif [ "$TIME" -lt 64800 ]; then
  echo "Good Afternoon"
else
  echo "Good evening"
fi
exit
```

All times are converted to seconds

Comment: @Maroun You're absolutely right. But his question had `H:m:s` format and I wasn't sure I can do that with `date` approach.