# How can I get the difference between a date/time string and the current time?

Tags: shell

I have a date-time in a shell script variable. How can I compare it with current timestamp and find out how many minutes the difference is between these two dates in a shell script?

The variable I have in a shell script has a value like `08/16/2019 15:34:00`.

Comment: The absolute difference? Or do you know that the timestamp you have is in the past? Also, did you try something, and how did it not work?

Answer (score 1):

To get the difference of the current time minus the provided timestamp (with GNU `date` and Bash 5.0 or newer), you could use the `EPOCHSECONDS` shell variable and the `-d` option of `date`:

```
$ echo $(((EPOCHSECONDS - $(date -d '08/16/2019 15:34:00' +%s)) / 60))
19
```

For Bash older than 5.0, you could use `printf '%(%s)T'` instead of `EPOCHSECONDS`:

```
echo $((($(printf '%(%s)T') - $(date -d '08/16/2019 15:34:00' +%s)) / 60))
```

And if you have a Bash older than 4.2 (or any POSIX shell), you have to use `date` twice:

```
echo $((($(date +%s) - $(date -d '08/16/2019 15:34:00' +%s)) / 60))
```

And if you don't have GNU `date` and its `-d` option, have a look at the Q&A at  [Parse Date in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1842634/3266847): parse the date/time string with `read`, or use `date`'s `-jf` flags on macOS.