# Read string date in bash with year and month only

Tags: bash, date

Is there a straightforward way to parse date in Bash with year and month only, eg in format `YYYY-mm`?

This does not work:

```bash
$ date -d "2022-12" +"%Y-%m"
date: invalid date ‘2022-12’
```

In Python, this works:

```py
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.strptime("2022-12", "%Y-%m")
datetime.datetime(2022, 12, 1, 0, 0)
```

Comment: please, review next posts:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1842634/parse-date-in-bash

Comment: I did, sadly there is no (simple) answer addressing my question. I did not account for rather complicated substitutions using `sed` and other tricks.

Comment: To see what datetime formats are valid for GNU date `-d`, read [29 Date input formats](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Date-input-formats.html#Date-input-formats). TL;DR omitting the year is OK, omitting the day is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct command is (at least it works for me MacOS):

```
date -jf "%Y-%m" "2022-12"
>Wed Dec 21 12:45:05 IST 2022
```

In your case date is incorrect since you doin't have day. The solution is simply add '01' day to source date:

```
my_date='2022-12'
date --date="${my_date}-01"
>Thu Dec  1 00:00:00 UTC 2022
```

Comment: On Ubuntu, this yields an error: `date: invalid option -- 'j'`.

Comment: After edit, this is an elegant solution: `date -d "${my_date}-01" + "%Y-%m`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Python is more flexible when it comes to date formats. It can accept different formats, such as "2022-12". However, the date command in bash requires a valid date format to be specified such as "2022-12-01" or "2022-12-31".

Comment: This is more a comment than an actual answer

Answer (score 0):

Create a function with a default daynumber (possible in `.bashrc`)

```
ymdate() {
  date -d "$1-1" +"%Y-%m-%d"
}
```

Next call the function like

```
ymdate 2022-12
```